# Does "&" vs. "&&" actually make a difference for compile-time flags?

Tags: c++, c, compilation

I have a habit of using the following syntax in my compile-time flags:

```
#if (defined(A) & defined(B))
```

It's usually suggested that I do it with the `&&` as follows:

```
#if (defined(A) && defined(B))
```

I know the difference between the two operators, and that in normal code  `&&` would short-circuit. However, the above is all handled by the compiler. Does it even matter what I use? Does it affect compile time by some infinitesimal amount because it doesn't evaluate the second `define()`?

Comment: When the 2 halves are either 0 or 1, no difference.

Comment: Don't write code that unnecessarily obscures what it's doing. C++ isn't Java.

Comment: @PeteBecker, How does my code obscure what it's doing?

Comment: @Catsunami -- the code is using a bitwise operator to do a logical and.

Comment: @PeteBecker, I'm not sure how that makes it obscure. It is using a bitwise AND on **boolean** values, which is very clear.

Comment: I would not say obscure, but not as logical... The intention is not to mask bits here. Its like doing: if (a * b) { ... } when your intention is to do if ( a && b) { ... }.  It may works, but the latter is more clear. This is not a preference.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Since `defined(SOMETHING)` yields 0 or 1, so that you're guaranteed 0 or 1 on both sides, it doesn't make a *technical* difference whether you use `&` or `&&`.

It's mostly about good habits (using `&` could carry over to some situation where it would be wrong) and about writing code that is easy to grasp by simple pattern matching. A `&` in there causes a millisecond pause while one considers whether it possibly could be a bit-level thing.

<del>On the third hand, you can't use keyword `and`, which you ¹can use in ordinary C++ code.</del>

<sup>*Notes:*

¹ With Visual C++ you can use `and` via a forced include of `<iso646.h>`.</sup>

Comment: I probably mistakenly thought the standard didn't support `and` in preprocessor conditionals, but it supports any integral constant expression (C++11 §16.1 "Conditional inclusion"). Fixed by overstrike. It's unclear because it says " except that identifiers (including those lexically identical to keywords) are interpreted as described below".

Comment: Yeah, it is not stated clearly, but `and` is not an identifier so the normal rules for identifiers do not apply.

Comment: MSVC has unofficially deprecated the ISO646 alternative tokens. I'm not really sure why, but they cannot be used (*anywhere*, not just in preprocessor conditionals) unless you manually include the header. Alternatively, you can throw the `/Ze` switch (which disables Microsoft language extensions, enabled by default with the `/Za` switch), and then these alternative tokens will be available everywhere without the need to include the header.

Comment: @CodyGray This sounds like you and/or MSVC have confused C with C++.  The ISO646 alternative tokens have never been available in any context in C, unless you include `<iso646.h>`, which defines them all as macros expanding to the traditional equivalent.  Conversely, in C++, they are supposed to be usable everywhere without including any header.

Answer (score 17):

According to the C99 standard, the expressions used in the preprocessor are constant expressions as defined by the C language itself, and are evaluated using the same engine.  Therefore, `&&` is a logical and operator that short circuits based on its LHS, and `&` is a bitwise operator with no predefined order of evaluation.

In practical terms, when used with `defined()` as you are, there is no difference between the two.  However, the following would show a difference:

```
#define A 2
#define B 5
#if (A && B)
printf("A && B\n");
#endif
#if (A & B)
printf("A & B"\n);
#endif
```

In this case, `A && B` will be output, but not `A & B` (since the result of that bitwise-and is `0`)

Answer (score 3):

I would like to add to the previous answers that it can actually matter a lot in a situation like this:

```
#define A 0
#define B 21
#if (A != 0) && (42 / A == B)
/* ... */
#endif
```

Here, if `A == 0`, the compiler will not break. Writing `(A != 0) & (42 / A == B)` will make the compiler complain about a division by zero.